# Настройка icecast2 relay на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, icecast

Нашел в интернете поток и хочу его вещать через `icecast`,настроил конфиг вроде все правильно,вбиваю в браузере адресс и пишут `Mount unavailable`.

```
<relay>
    <server>http://online.radiorecord.ru/</server>
    <port>8102</port>
    <mount>/club_128</mount>
    <local-mount>/club_128</local-mount>
    <on-demand>1</on-demand>
    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
```

Вот такую ошибку в логах нашел:

```
[2016-12-13  10:47:42] WARN fserve/fserve_client_create req for file "/usr/share/icecast2/web/club_128" No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE:** Разобрался вместо адреса хоста вбил айпи и заработало, в чем разница-то?

Comment: <server>online.radiorecord.ru</server> --   error.log -- log level 4

Comment: и что это означает?

Comment: заменить "server". установить 'LogLevel'. перезапуск Icecast. посмотреть на 'error.log'

Comment: Ну сервер рабочий,я на данный момент слушаю этот поток.

Comment: /etc/init.d/icecast2 reload

Comment: Перезапускал,всеравно ничего

Answer (score 0):

Убери http:// и слэш на конце и все работает.

```
<relay>
    <server>online.radiorecord.ru</server>
    <port>8102</port>
    <mount>/club_128</mount>
    <local-mount>/club_128</local-mount>
    <on-demand>1</on-demand>
    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
```